# Delete message in a specific channel

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to delete an old message in a specific channel with my bot.
The code below doesn't work and I don't why.

```js
if (msg.channel == channelDLid) {
  msg.delete(6000);
}
```

The code is executed but it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Channel#bulkDelete`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) which allows you to delete up to 2-week old messages.
To only delete specific messages you can use [`Channel#fetchMessages`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessages) like:

```
const messages = await message.channel.fetchMessages({ limit: 100}) // Fetch last 100 messages
  .then(msgs => msgs.first(msgs.size - 3)) // Remove the last 3 messages out of the collection to delete

message.channel.bulkDelete(messages, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the channel with the id, you should write:

```
if (msg.channel.id == channelDLid) {
  msg.delete(6000);
}
```

Comment: ok how to delete all old messages in a specific channel from my bot ?
and just don't delete the 4 last message ?

Comment: For that, look at the answer from Plasma Chicken